# How to hide the title of the product on Woocommerce widget "Recently Viewed"

Tags: wordpress, widget, woocommerce

I love this widget, but I only need the image of the product, not the name. I attached a picture to show what I mean, I only want that the widget to show the image of the product. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bD9nh.png)

Answer (score 1):

select its class and add display : none ;

Comment: its better if you can provide a complete example to him and a screenshot as well